# MySQL query runs fine in command line, but gives error when ran in php

Tags: php, mysql

I have a query that works fine when I run it on my linux server command line, but when i try to execute i through php, it throws a php error.

```
SELECT h.timestamp, d.valueparam, r.label, r.dataUnit 
FROM EventData d, EventHeader h, EventKeyReference r 
WHERE h.id = d.eventHeader_id AND h.serialNumber=$serialnumber 
AND d.keyParam='G002' AND r.EventKey = 'G002' 
ORDER BY h.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

It gives me this error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;  check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'AND d.keyParam='G002' AND r.EventKey = 'G002' ORDER BY
>   h.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1' at line 1

Does anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: In PHP, echo your query to the screen and see what it shows.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My guess: `$serialnumber` is empty, your query is:

```
SELECT h.timestamp, d.valueparam, r.label, r.dataUnit 
FROM EventData d, EventHeader h, EventKeyReference r 
WHERE h.id = d.eventHeader_id AND h.serialNumber=
                                               // ^-- error here
AND d.keyParam='G002' AND r.EventKey = 'G002' 
ORDER BY h.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: Thank you, such a stupid mistake, this has bugged me for hours. I had written $serialNumber where I used the function that ran the query. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Update your query as below, it will work even serialnumber is empty

```
$sql = "SELECT h.timestamp, d.valueparam, r.label, r.dataUnit 
FROM EventData d, EventHeader h, EventKeyReference r 
WHERE h.id = d.eventHeader_id AND h.serialNumber='".$serialnumber."'
AND d.keyParam='G002' AND r.EventKey = 'G002' 
ORDER BY h.timestamp DESC LIMIT 1";
```

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
AND h.serialNumber=$serialnumber
```

into

```
AND h.serialNumber='$serialnumber'
```

This will catch any empty $serialnumber or $serialnumber with letters in it.